# whether intel e7-4807 support Pause-loop exiting

Tags: hardware, virtualization

whether intel e7-4807 support Pause-loop exiting

and from which version does libvirt support Pause-loop exiting.

Thanks.
I have searched google for long, but no result.  Feel very confused.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is still relevant after a month and a half, and if you have one of those processors, run a VirtualBox virtual machine on it and check the log file for VMX_VMCS_CTRL_PROC_EXEC_CONTROLS_PAUSE_EXIT (exit on pause) and/or VMX_VMCS_CTRL_PROC_EXEC2_PAUSE_LOOP_EXIT (exit on a specified number of pause loops).